# Split out certain part of string with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have different strings of the form `_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs (SGYA)]AHUDSHDI_` and I want to cut out the `(SGYA)` part (always capital letters in round brackets) and eventual spaces directly before or after it. So the result should be `_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI_`.

I had the idea of matching the content of the square brackets with `([A-Z_])(\[.+\])([A-Z_])` and then doing a split and re-inserting it using `re` module (although I am not sure which `re` function is suited for this).

However, this feels inelegant. Is there a `regex` that would do what I want directly, without the intermediary steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(\[[^][]*?)\s*\([A-Z]*\)\s*([^][]*])', r'\1\2', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cm0Ljj/2)

**Details**

- `(\[[^][]*?)` - Group 1: a `[` and then any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` -  a `(` char
- `[A-Z]*` - 0+ uppercase ASCII letters
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^][]*])` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `]` and `[` (as many as possible) and then a `]`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/AUdOAQ):

```
import re
rx = r"(\[[^][]*?)\s*\([A-Z]*\)\s*([^][]*])"
s = "_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs (SGYA)]AHUDSHDI"
print( re.sub(rx, r'\1\2', s) )
# => _AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI
```

Another idea: only remove all `\s*\([A-Z]+\)\s*` matches when found inside `[...]` substrings:

```
import re
s = "_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs (SGYA)]AHUDSHDI"
print( re.sub(r"\[[^][]+]", lambda x: re.sub(r'\s*\([A-Z]+\)\s*', "", x.group()), s) )
# => _AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/8LnZTy).

Here, the `\[[^][]+]` pattern will find all chunks of `[`, then 1+ chars other than square brackets and then a `]`, and then any occurrences of 0+ whitespaces, `(`, 1+ uppercase ASCII letters, `)` and 0+ whitespaces will be removed only inside the matches found with the `\[[^][]+]` pattern.

Comment: The regex can be simplified to `r'(?:\s?\((.*?)\))'` since OP just want to get rid of what is inside `()` and any preceding spaces. Check my answer.

Comment: @accdias Well, OP added some more requirements for that, see *always capital letters in round brackets*. `\(.*?\)` will "overfire".

Comment: Indeed but I'm _guessing_ he just wanted to mean _anything_ inside round brackets. But it is just a guess and you're being more precise anyway.

Comment: @accdias It should only be capital letters. Matching everything is not wrong, of course, but only matching capital letters is more concise indeed.

Comment: @accdias In the very first regex I wrote in my answer I used `\([^][()]*\)`, to make sure I stay within `[...]` and match any chars inside `(...)` but parentheses. Then, I paid attention to the *capital letters* restriction.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re


weirdstring =  "_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs (SGYA)]AHUDSHDI_"
weirdstring = re.sub(r'(.*?)(\s*\(.*?\)\s*)(.*?)', r'\1\3', weirdstring)

print(weirdstring)

# prints _AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI_
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> s='_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs (SGYA)]AHUDSHDI_'
>>> re.sub(r'(?:\s?\((.*)\))', '', s)
'_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI_'
>>>
```

If you want to only match capital letters inside square brackets, then the expression should be:

```py
>>> re.sub(r'(?:\s?\(([A-Z]+)\))', '', s)
'_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI_'
>>>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 capturing groups and in the replacement use both capturing groups `\1\2`

```
([A-Z_]+\[[^(\s]+)[^\S\r\n]*\([A-Z]+\)[^\S\r\n]*(\][A-Z_]+)
```

In parts

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z_]+` Match 1+ chars `A-Z` or `_`
  - `\[[^(\s]+` Match `[` and 1+ any chars except the listed
- `)` Close group
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars except newline
- `\([A-Z]+\)` Match chars `A-Z` between parenthesis
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ whitespace chars except newline
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\][A-Z_]+` Match `]` and 1+ chars `A-Z` or `_`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ColcBv/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TlbXRu)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"([A-Z_]+\[[^(\s]+)[^\S\r\n]*\([A-Z]+\)[^\S\r\n]*(\][A-Z_]+)"
test_str = "_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs (SGYA)]AHUDSHDI_"
print(re.sub(regex, r"\1\2", test_str))
```

Output

```
_AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI_
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the re.sub function

```
import re
s = "AHDHDUHD[Tsfs (SGYA)]AHUDSHDI" 
s_re = re.sub("(.*?)(\s*\(.*?\)\s*)(.*?)", '', s)
print (s_re)
```

It will print:

```
AHDHDUHD[Tsfs]AHUDSHDI
```

Comment: Check the desired output. Your solution is not what OP wants.

Comment: Yeap, the solution of Wiktor Stribiżew is more appropriate. I changed the regex in order to have the desired output.